# Double-blue underlines in MS Word

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office-2013

I have a document with an entire paragraph double-underlined in blue.
There's another post of the same name where a respondent says it's due to "wordiness."  I do believe I'm looking at an example of wordiness, but being a legal contract, this isn't a section I want to change.

I've run the grammar and spelling checks, and this section is not addressed by those.  I've looked in Options --> Proofing and unchecked everything grammar-related, but it has not changed this double-underline.  There are no suggestions when I right-click either.

The other response I read said to turn off "wordiness" under Preferences.  Preferences is not a heading I can find anywhere so we must be looking at different versions of Word.

I'm using Professional Plus 2013.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In Word 2013, I found a place to turn on/off the `wordiness` checking.

- The File menu in the main ribbon.
- Options
- Proofing
- The `Settings` button in the "When correcting spelling and grammar..." section.
- Scroll way down.
- Check/uncheck the `Wordiness` option.